Finding a specific item in a list using CLI
I am using the CLI and the determined library, and I want to find if a certain Username exists.
I tried the commands below, but I dont get the line printed although I'm sure the Username exists.
Assume the username is xyz, and the column name is Username (other columns are User Id etc.)
det user ls | grep -E "^Username: (${xyz})$"
det user ls | awk "/Username: ${xyz}$/ {print $0}"
det user ls | awk '$3 == "xyz"'
I use $3 because it is the third column.
just to be clear, det user ls does work!
I'd like it to be a one liner and not a script (to avoid uploading to the system).
I guess there is an issue with the logic? or I'm doing the search wrong?
thanks in advance

EDIT 1:
Below is an example of how the det user ls looks like:
det user ls
   User Id | Name      | Username       | Active 
-----------+-----------+----------------+----------  
       325 | abc       | xyz            | False


You'd have to show us the output of det user ls if you want us to help you write code to parse the output of det user ls. Your code has a mixture of double quotes ("), single quotes (') and smart quotes (“, ”, and ’) - clean that up in your question and in your real code if you really are using smart quotes. Also clarify if  xyz is the user name or the name of a shell variable that contains the user name. Please [edit] your question to address all of that, don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

You say I use $3 because it is the third column. but if xyz should match a string in the 3rd column then grep -E "^Username: (${xyz})$" can't possibly work as that regexp tries to match Username: in the first column and (${xyz}) in the 2nd column, not the 3rd, plus the ^ and $ around the regexp mean the line must only contain those 2 strings, no additional columns, but you said other columns are User Id etc. We really need to see some det user ls output to be able to help you.

edited, could you help further plz

In the sample input you provided:
$ cat file
   User Id | Name      | Username       | Active
-----------+-----------+----------------+----------
       325 | abc       | xyz            | False

the value you want to output, xyz is the 5th space-separated field, not the 3rd, so:
$ cat file | awk 'NR>2{print $5}'
xyz

or if you wanted to use |s surrounded by optional spaces as the field separator:
$ cat file | awk -F'[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' 'NR>2{print $3}'
xyz

Replace cat file with det user ls of course. The above will work using any POSIX awk.

thanks, det user ls | awk 'NR>2{print $5}' works! It now shows all the usernames in my list, but my question was how do I find if in this column xyz appears. For example, if I have 100 rows in det user ls, and I want to check if xyz is one of the Usernames there? Could you help with this please

@ArieAI accept an answer to this question you asked and then ask a new question as chameleon questions are strongly discouraged.

The question actually was "Finding a specific item in a list using CLI" ("I want to find if a certain Username exists"). So if I try to recreate the question it will be marked as duplicated. Of course I will accept as answered then. thanks a lot again!
